# Need help implementing in-app purchase from helper class

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I am trying IAP for the first time and I need some help connecting the dots.

My app has two different non-consumable IAPs which I have set up in a "product" class if its own like this:

```
enum IAPProduct: String{
    case tempoLevels  = ".....TempoLevels"
    case timingLevels = ".....TimingLevels"
}
```

Then I set up a helper class via a tutorial I found like this:

```
class IAPService: NSObject  {
    private override init() {}
    static let shared = IAPService()

    var products = [SKProduct]()
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

    func getProducts() {
        let products: Set = [IAPProduct.tempoLevels.rawValue, IAPProduct.timingLevels.rawValue]

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        paymentQueue.add(self)
    }

    func purchase(product: IAPProduct) {
        guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }).first
            else {return}
        let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
        paymentQueue.add(payment)
    }
}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        for product in response.products {
            print(product.localizedTitle)
        }
    }   
}

extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing: break
            default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
    func status() -> String{
        switch self{
            case .deferred: return "deferred"
            case .failed: return "failed"
            case .purchased: return "purchased"
            case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
            case .restored: return "restored" 

        @unknown default:
            return("Something is wrong...")
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to trigger some functions in another view controller when the product is purchased. How do I do this?

I sort of set up a function in one of the view controllers that checks UserDefaults in one of the view controllers like this:

```
func isPurchased() -> Bool {
    let purchaseStatus = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: ??)

    if purchaseStatus == true {
        print("Previously purchased!")
        return true
    }else{
        print("Never purchased!")
        return false
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can use this function, but if I can somehow, I have code in my app that would work with it if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly `SKPaymentTransactionState` for purchase checking.

You can call like thi after creating the transaction if want to Bool value

```
func isPurchased(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) -> Bool {
  return transaction.transactionState == .purchased
}
```

or directly String value from extension ofSKPaymentTransactionState

```
func isPurchased(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) -> String {
      return transaction.status
    }
```

In the mean time, **you should not ever** store a boolean for checking if user has bought in-app purchase in UserDefaults. User can change it very easily (without jailbreaking) and get your goodies for free! **You should Use Keychain instead of UserDefaults.**

Comment: "User can change it very easily" How would the user do that?

Comment: @matt iExplorer and iFunBox are two examples of software that allow you to explore iOS’ filesystem without having your phone jailbroken. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do they actually give you access to the contents of UserDefaults?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. I have tried to place this function that returns a bool in the view controller that I am using, and I get an error that says: Cannot convert return expression of type 'SKPaymentTransactionState' to return type 'Bool'

Comment: @TerryB Sorry, i fixed that. Now you can use.

Comment: @matt Yes, according to many articles and tutorials that I read.

Comment: Ok great, thank you! I am not sure exactly what to pass in as the parameter here when I call the function

Comment: Yes, I found a tutorial about storing this info in the keychain: https://fluffy.es/check-purchased-iap-using-keychain/

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting closer. I passed in transaction, but since I declared transaction as an array in the helper class I am now getting an error that says: Cannot convert value of type '[SKPaymentTransaction]' to expected argument type 'SKPaymentTransaction'

Comment: Do you wanna get all transaction status? Because you used transaction array instead of a transaction..@TerryB